# double free or corruption(fasttop)

Tags: c, memory-management

Hello guys I have an array resizing function like this

```
int
add_time_element (time_t *array, time_t element, size_t *size)
{
    if (NULL == array)
    {
        return STATUS_FAIL;
    }

    int status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    time_t *tmp = NULL;
    size_t local_size;

    (*size)++;
    local_size = *size;

    printf ("Local size %lu\n", local_size);

    tmp = realloc (array, local_size * sizeof (time_t));
    if (NULL == tmp)
    {
        status = STATUS_FAIL;   
    }
    else 
    {
        array = tmp;
    }

    if (STATUS_FAIL == status)
    {   
        (*size)--;
    }
    else
    {
        array[local_size - ONE] = element;
    }

    return status;  
}
```

I am calling this function like this..

```
  time_t *dates = NULL;
    dates = malloc (ONE);
    for (slot_index = ZERO; slot_index < data_provider->n_slots; slot_index++)
    {
        printf ("Testing\n");
        /*slot = data_provider->slots[slot_index];
        date = get_date (slot->start_time);*/
        date += ONE;    
        if (STATUS_FAIL ==  add_unique_time_element (dates, date, &n_dates))
        {
            free (dates);
            dates = NULL;   
            return STATUS_FAIL;
        }
    }
```

I am getting the double free(fasttop) error in realloc function..

And valgrind analysis report says

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==22491==    at 0x4C2DD9F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22491==    by 0x402BA3: add_time_element (array_util.c:353)
==22491==    by 0x402C6C: add_unique_time_element (array_util.c:399)
==22491==    by 0x401F92: create_dates (data_provider.c:283)
==22491==    by 0x401D7D: create_data_provider_file (data_provider.c:174)
==22491==    by 0x4075CC: main (data_provider_test.c:13)
==22491==  Address 0x5b63170 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==22491==    at 0x4C2DD9F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22491==    by 0x402BA3: add_time_element (array_util.c:353)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the prototype of your function is

`int
add_time_element (time_t *array, time_t element, size_t *size)`

you're changing `array` in your routine, but it does not reflect on the caller, you're changing a *copy* of the `array` pointer.

So, next time you call your routine, if `array` has been changed by `realloc` at some point because it needed more size (doesn't happen systematically), you're passing an already freed pointer.

Possible fixes:

- return `array` instead of your status (returning `NULL` when fails would be OK)
- pass `array` as `time_t **array` and refer to it as `*array` in your routine (and call with `&array`)

(first alternative is simpler)

Note: the rest of your code is remarkably well-written against error handling (that's the irony of the thing)

Comment: Is the array not updated. As it is a memory location?

Comment: the array is _copied_ somewhere else (not _moved_ so you may believe your program works for a moment, that's the vicious part). You have to export the return value of `realloc` to your caller.